# Access is blocked in OAuth 2.0 Playground google

Tags: oauth2-playground

I'm trying to create a 'Refresh Token' to send an email via nodemailer.
I created an 'OAuth 2.0 client' key,
And I continued to create the token by this link: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
I put the Client ID and Client secret in the configuration and wrote in the input: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send
And when I click the 'authoriz apis' button of step 1, I get this error:
Access is blocked: This app's request is invalid
Unable to sign in because an invalid request was sent by this app. You can try again later or contact the developer about the problem. More information about this error
Developers of this app can refer to Error details.
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch